# My NE555 circuit triggers falsely when connected to the mains using a 5V adapter

Tags: mains, laser, ldr, 555, monostable

I have designed a laser security system using an NE555 in monostable mode with a potentiometer to adjust the pulse length. Another NE555 (U2) ciruit is used for delaying power on the monostable circuit so that the laser reaches the LDR first and the circuit doesn't trigger at start. Both are turned on using a double pole switch. There is a relay so that when the 5V adapter is delivering power the circuit uses that not the output from the power bank circuit (which is ~3V when charging.) The power bank has one IC which does not have a label.

The problem is that the circuit works fine when powered using the battery, but when I switch to power from the adapter it triggers after the delay of the U2 in the schematic.

I have tried a few different 5V adapters. One seems to work but after a while the circuit gets triggered.

What can I do to prevent this?

I am new to hardware stuff so my schematic is not something I am proud of.

[image: this is the schematic]

Comment: What's the ripple on the power supply look like?

Comment: I don't have a scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like R12 and the capacitor-resistor pair of R14 and C4 should swap places.  I'm not trying to understand the full circuit, mind, but it seems counter-intuitive, especially since R14 seems to be doing the job of discharging the timing cap C4.